# How can I handle proxy servers with LWP::Simple?

Tags: perl, proxy, lwp

How can I add proxy support to this script?

```
use LWP::Simple;

$url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$word = "how to ask";
$content = get $url;
if($content =~ m/$word/)
{
print "Found $word";
}
```

Comment: If you has simply googled this, the very first hit would have told you the answer!

Comment: Well, google is the answer for almost all of the questions here, but if I were maintaining a FAQ for LWP I'd put this question in it. :)

Answer (score 13):

Access the underlying LWP::UserAgent object and set the proxy. LWP::Simple exports the `$ua` variable so you can do that:

```
use LWP::Simple qw( $ua get );
$ua->proxy( 'http', 'http://myproxy.example.com' );
my $content = get( 'http://www.example.com/' );
```